# Sublime Text removes backslash when entering double quotes and a comma

Tags: c, sublimetext3

I am trying to write C/C++ statements in Sublime Text, but keep having to undo the last change because Sublime Text automatically removes the backslash in `\n`.

When I am trying to write this, for example:

```
printf("string is %s\n", s);
```

I get this after I type `",`:

```
printf("string is %sn", s);
```

It does not happen when the last double quote does not exist yet:

```
printf("string is %s\n ...);
```

Is there a way to prevent this behavior?

Comment: Sounds like a plugin is causing issues. What plugins do you have installed? Alternatively, you can enter `sublime.log_commands(True)` in the ST console and see whats running when you enter the `",`.

Comment: @skuroda Thanks for the tip, but it's not showing anything when I do that action. It shows something for everything else, but the backslash just disappears with no log message.

Comment: I can't duplicate this behavior using ST3 on OSX 10.8.5. For one thing, your quotes should be auto-completed, so you shouldn't have to type the closing quote before the comma...

Comment: OK, never mind, I can replicate this when the quotes are automatically paired, but you type the closing quote anyway, or even if you don't type the closing quote, but use the right arrow key to move beyond the quote.

Comment: @MattDMo Actually, I have bracket/quote matching turned on, I've just noticed that when I *delete* the final double quote and then re-type the backslash, it does not disappear when I manually add the `",`. Typically, I type *over* the already-existing double quote (force of habit from other IDEs and text editors).

Comment: @Abluescarab - yes, I discovered that too. I'm currently trying to figure out *why*, I'll get back to you if I find anything.

Comment: @Abluescarab Hmm I'm still having trouble reproducing the issue. I'm still leaning towards a plugin causing the issue. Perhaps if you list those, MattDMo can use them to help identify what you have in common. I do have a follow up question though. If you record a macro, enter the text and stop the macro, what happens if you replay the macro?

Comment: @skuroda Well, my list of plugins is pretty long. I should probably download the portable version of ST3 and try it without plugins, but the same settings. I have noticed that it doesn't happen when I have it set to the Plain Text syntax. It only happens when typing code that has autocomplete. I'm also not aware how to make a macro in Sublime Text. Do I just record a macro entering the text I want, then replay it, but stopping in the middle?

Comment: @Abluescarab Go to `Tools -> Record Macro`, enter the text as you would normally. Then go back to the `Tools -> Stop Recording Macro`. There is also a `Playback Macro` entry in the Tools menu you can use to replay it. Finally, you can save it to a file, and see what commands it has recorded.

Comment: @skuroda It actually worked as desired. The backslash did not disappear.

Comment: So I see the command "afn_delete_prefixed_slash" but how do I stop that now?